# ReadProcessMemory Always fails with GLE: 299

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

Could someone please help me, I do not know why the ReadProcessMemory function fails and GetLastError = 299. Here is my code, I can't see that im doing anything wrong.

```
if(ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)0, IDH_Buffer, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER), 0) != true)
        std::cout << "Failed to read from Process, GLE=" << GetLastError()  << "\n";
```

IDH_Buffer has be assigned, hProcess is non NULL

My App is running as Admin and the app that im trying to read from is a standard usermode application.

Please could you advise me. 
Thanks

Comment: You should not compare the return values from system functions to "true" you should check them for being "== false".  The reason is on error it is guaranteed to return 0.  On sucess it can return anything else.  Comparing to "true" is incorrect.  But, this probably isn't your problem.

Comment: A process starts at address 0x400000, not 0.  Well, back in the olden days anyway, ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) mucked that up.  Mostly to stop you from doing what you intend to do.  You really do need to use VirtualQueryEx() to find out where stuff is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [MSDN on Win32 error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
> 299 (0x12B)
> Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

My guess is the address you specified contained some valid data, but somewhere between that address and (address + length of copy), there was no memory mapped.

See [wikipedia on page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) or [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) to understand a bit more about how an operating system establishes an address space.  In that parlance, somewhere in that memory range there was a page table entry that was not valid.

Actually, looking at your code...  It's obvious that this won't work.  The `BaseAddress` parameter is zero.  You're trying to dereference a NULL pointer in the other process's address space.  If the target process itself tried to pull this, it would crash.  :-)  The EXE's header is not mapped to address 0.  If you are trying to read from the EXE file itself, I would suggest simply calling `CreateFile` on a path obtained by `GetModuleFileNameEx`.